# How to hide the overlays in A frame?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I want the Aframe default screen to be in a small portion of my site, so first I want to hide the overlays, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was only `aframe` i'd suggest embedding it:

```
<div id="myEmbeddedScene">
   <a-scene embedded>
      <!--- ---!>
```

---

To keep the `ar.js` video from getting onto your entire website, i'd suggest throwing it to an iframe:

```
<iframe src="ar.html"></iframe>
```

Glitch [here](http://%20%3Ciframe%20src=%22ar.html%22%20width=%22300px%22%20height=%22300px%22%3E%3C/iframe%3E).

---

If you want to get rid of the `ar.js` `debugUI`, you can disable it:

```
<a-scene arjs="debugUIEnabled: false">
```